# How can I prompt the user for a value in response to a RightTapped event?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8

I need to prompt the user for textual input when they right-click or -tap a grid in a `GridView`. How do I do that? Do I need to create a custom `user control` or is there some way to use a `Popup` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Callisto library](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto) that includes a lightweight flyout control.